# No module named 'Resource'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, python-import, spyder

I'm using Python 3.7 version on Spyder in windows 10 machine. I'm trying to import blend module in Spyder. I have successfully installed module blend using pip command on Terminal, however when I try to run this command it is showing an import error for the module Resource. I have then tried to install resource module in terminal and it got installed successfully. Both blend and resource modules are installed and I still see this import error when I'm running this command on Spyder.

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install blend

Requirement already satisfied: blend in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.1.5)


(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>blend

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\blend", line 3, in <module>
    import blend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\blend\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from Resource import Resource
ImportError: No module named 'Resource'

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install Resource


Requirement already satisfied: Resource in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-easyconfig>=0.1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Resource) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: JsonForm>=0.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Resource) (0.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: JsonSir>=0.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Resource) (0.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-easyconfig>=0.1.0->Resource) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-easyconfig>=0.1.0->Resource) (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from JsonForm>=0.0.2->Resource) (2.6.0)

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>blend

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\blend", line 3, in <module>
    import blend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\blend\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from Resource import Resource
ImportError: No module named 'Resource'
```

Answer (score 0):

blend seems to be quite old ([last commit 6 year ago](https://github.com/azavea/blend/commit/2cafbc326f2e6b3f1947581cca860ff544adada1), [last release](https://pypi.org/project/Blend/0.1.5/) at Feb 16, 2013). It [doesn't list any dependency](https://github.com/azavea/blend/blob/2cafbc326f2e6b3f1947581cca860ff544adada1/setup.py#L52) so I'm sure it doesn't require [package Resource](https://pypi.org/project/Resource/), it's trying to import [its own module Resource](https://github.com/azavea/blend/blob/master/blend/Resource.py) but it imports the module using absolute import which is Python2-way of importing.

So I'm sure the code is Python2-only.